# How to get previous behaviour of alt-tab task switcher in 11.10

Tags: unity, 11.10, shortcut-keys, application-switcher, tabs

When I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> the task switcher appears. Unfortunately, the behaviour in 11.10 has changed.

Previously, in 11.04, I would see all applications, I could see if an application was minimised (it would only show the icon) and I would see a preview of the window.

Now, in 11.10, I only see a list of icons, I can see if more than one is actually started (by checking the small arrows on the side --as on the dash). I do not see a preview. For the preview I either have to wait. Long. Afaik this time is not configurable. Or I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> then the preview appears immediately, but unfortunately there is no way to then return to my list (and continue cycling through the list). Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> again has no effect.

Is there an alternative task-switcher? Is there a way to get back to the task switcher from 11.04?

Comment: The answers at [How do I revert Alt-tab behavior to switch between windows on the current workspace?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/68151/how-do-i-revert-alt-tab-behavior-to-switch-between-windows-on-the-current-worksp) explain how to get all of the classic behavior of alt-tab via "Static Application Switcher", and are more detailed than the explanation given by xmanmonk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> or the up arrow key <kbd>↑</kbd> will close the preview.

Answer (score 3):

I like the previews as well. First, I made sure CompizConfig was installed. I brought it up and disabled static application switcher, then enabled application switcher (there were some keybinding conflicts with Unity's switching behavior, but I just chose to favor the application switcher keys). This worked for me.