# Alt-Tab Behaviour, Windows from

Tags: 11.10, unity, compiz

I am wondering about the behaviour of the Alt-Tab :
All windows are shown, whereas before (sure on 10.10, can't remember on 11.04) we could just see the windows of the current workspace.
Therefore the number of windows displayed is much more important !

Could you please help me ?

Comment: you use to be able to set this, i'm now using kubuntu so not where to check in the new version of Unity. It should be under window behavior or something like that. maybe under the compiz settings if those are still around.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get previous behaviour of alt-tab task switcher in 11.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66935/how-to-get-previous-behaviour-of-alt-tab-task-switcher-in-11-10)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is not configurable for the new window switcher which is part of Unity in 11.10.

Personally I fix this by disabling the shortcuts for the new integrated switcher and using a different window switcher.  There are at least 4 other window/application switcher plugins in Compiz and most (or all?) of the other switchers can be configured to either show all windows or only those on the current workspace.

You can edit the Compiz configuration when you install `compizconfig-settings-manager` & run "CompizConfig Settings Manager".

An additional advantage is that these alternative switchers actually work and show all application windows (including those of Java apps and some legacy apps, which for some reason aren't shown by the Unity switcher).

Comment: I probably made a mistake, but I tried different settings to find the application switcher from Compiz, and now it seems to me that I have disabled Unity...
Now, I am on Unity2D, which still works fine...
Thanks for help :)