# How to get previous behaviour of alt-tab task switcher in 11.10?

Tags: application-switcher

This question was asked before:
[How to get previous behaviour of alt-tab task switcher in 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66935/how-to-get-previous-behaviour-of-alt-tab-task-switcher-in-11-10)

But the accepted answer did not answer the question.

The 11.10 task switcher is way to slow. It does not show all of the apps running. It only shows categories, then after a long pause it shows the instances in each category.

I want to go back to the better solution in Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: Categories? What are you referring to?

Comment: Not an answer (which is why it's a comment) but did you know that the down arrow key will expand the selections instantly without the pause.

Comment: If you have multiple instance of same program running, you can get preview in `alt+tab` with "alt+`" and change between instances with same key combination.

Answer (score 3):

Although this isnt exactly <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, do you know about <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>? it shows all the apps that are running.

Comment: Wow, I like that one, thanks. Anybody know a good source for shortcut descriptions.