# How do I turn off alt-tab in Unity?

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I revert Alt-tab behavior changed in 11.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68151/how-do-i-revert-alt-tab-behavior-changed-in-11-10)

Is there any way to turn off the way that Unity handles Alt-Tab? You know, to make it where Alt-Tab JUST switches through windows and doesn't group them?

Comment: When closing as a duplicate, it would be helpful to link to an actual duplicate.  Here is the best I could find: [unity - How to get previous behaviour of alt-tab task switcher in 11.10 - Ask Ubuntu - Stack Exchange](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66935/how-to-get-previous-behaviour-of-alt-tab-task-switcher-in-11-10).  An update for this quesion on Precise would be helpful.  Unity has lots of great stuff, but lack of useful previews for browser windows drives me crazy.